# User posted their password!

Tags: discussion, support

An asker on a question I am working on posted some code that contains their site password if you look deeply at it. How can I alert the user to take this down without posting it publicly on the question, thus calling even more attention to it?

Answer (score 17):

'Flag' the post for moderator attention and explain the problem. They can remove the password and redact the edit history.

Comment: After the password is removed, the mods (or the OP) should also ping the asker to change his/her password ASAP.